# Is it a good convention to add parameter on PUT method?

Tags: spring, rest, put

Say, The put method can return includeExtraTitle field by the given param
However, Is it a good idea to add param on `PUT` method? 
Is this a good practice?

```
@PutMapping(value = "/articles/{articleId}") 
Article put(@RequestParam(value = "includeExtraTitle", defaultValue = "false") boolean includeExtraTitle)
```

Comment: you mean request parameter? but your path variable is still unused(just saying)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/articles/{articleId}?includeExtraTitle=true
```

is a perfectly fine identifier for a resource.

`PUT` is a method in the uniform interface, so applying PUT semantics to this resource is fine (if you decide that isn't supported, you would respond with [405 Method Not Allowed](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.5)).

```
/articles/{articleId}
/articles/{articleId}?includeExtraTitle=true
/articles/{articleId}?includeExtraTitle=false
```

You should understand that, from the point of view of the client, these are identifiers for *different* resources.  `PUT /articles/{articleId}?includeExtraTitle=false` won't [invalidate](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-4.4) the client's locally cached copy of `/articles/{articleId}`, because the identifiers don't match.

The fact that these three resources happen to use the same "endpoint" is an accident of your implementation, and hidden from clients behind the uniform interface.

It's perfectly normal, though not necessarily common, for a single resource to have multiple representations.  So check that your use case isn't a better fit for varying the content-type, rather than varying the URI.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, It's an absolutely good approach.

Adding parameters for HTTP request types such as POST, PUT etc is exactly fine and recommended approach.